# How to Validate and Sanitize Form Checkbox Array?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, octobercms

I'm using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/) based on [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) and [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

I have a form with checkboxes `queued[]`. They are submitted and deleted with Laravel using a loop.

It all works but how can I [validate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#validating-arrays) and sanitize the array?

Validate requires an asterisk *? `'*' => Input::get('queued')`?

Sanitize, I get the error `trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`.

Form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_current() }}"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="_handler" value="onDelete" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="queued[]" value="item1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="queued[]" value="item2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="queued[]" value="item3" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="delete">Delete Checked</button>
</form>
```

PHP

```
public function onDelete() {

    # Validator
    $validator = Validator::make(
        [
            '_handler' => Input::get('_handler'),
            'queued' => Input::get('queued'),
            'submit' => Input::get('submit')
        ]
    );
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);
        exit();
    }

    # Sanitize
    function sanitize_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = strip_tags($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

    # Delete Checked
    $checkboxes = '';
    $checkboxes = isset($_POST['queued']) ? $_POST['queued'] : array();
    // Sanitize
    $checkboxes = $this->sanitize_input($checkboxes);

    foreach($checkboxes as $file) {        
        File::delete("$file");
    } 
}
```

Comment: i have solution for validation it will work as `'queued[]' => Input::get('queued'),` Try it please

Comment: what is $data which you passing in sanitize_input  method?

Comment: @recoverymen $data is just any form input passed into the function. I pass $checkboxes into it. I'll update the code.

Comment: ok... is validation working for you this time?

Comment: @recoverymen It passes the validator, but how do I know if it has validated each item in the array or if it is just checking the last queued[]?

Comment: here data will go in form of array and queued[] have array in it if you want to test you can get form request as $queued= $request->input('queued'); and dd($queued);

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own custom validation rules.
You can define a new rule in the plugins `boot()` method like this:

```
Validator::extend('myCustomRule', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    # check if the $value is in valid
    # return true if it is and return false if it is not valid
    return true;
});
```

You can foreach the array and then check the values. Depends on you validation rules, you might not need to sanitize after that.

And then you can use the custom rule by the name you supplied:

```
$validator = Validator::make(input(), [
    'queued' => 'myCustomRule',
    ]
);
```